# Query in Active Record Rails does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to use Rails' active record to generate something before_save and save it to a field. It's using two tables (Message and Spec)

My models/message.rb file looks like this:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :specs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :specs
  before_save :generate_output

  def generate_output
    self.output = "hola"
    specs_array = Spec.where(message_id: self.id).order('id asc')
    specs_array.each do |spec|
        self.output = "hello"
        if spec.call
          self.output += Message.find(name: spec).output
        else
          self.output += spec.specification
        end
      end
    self.output
  end
end
```

and my models/spec.rb file:

```
class Spec < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :message
end
```

And here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171121153642) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "output"
  end

  create_table "specs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "specification"
    t.boolean "call"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "message_id"
    t.index ["message_id"], name: "index_specs_on_message_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "specs", "messages"
end
```

I have a message form, that upon submission, saves a 'name' to Message table and 3 Specifications (and their message_id) to Spec table. It should also generate and save an output (as you can see in the message model) based on the specs in the Message table.

but these two lines of code in the model do not work:

```
    specs_array = Spec.where(message_id: self.id).order('id asc')
    specs_array.each do |spec|
```

I know the ones before them are working, because when I create a new message, its output is saved as 'hola' and if these two lines work, it should be saved as 'hello'+ whatever the message is.

I have tried the query in rails console, and it totally works fine, any idea why it's not working in the app?
thanks!

edit:
My controller method that calls for save (it's Rails generic method):

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the private method for messasge_params:

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, specs_attributes: [:id, :call, :specification])
end
```

Comment: Your `Message` instance doesn't have an `id` yet in `before_save` callback if you create it.

Comment: You use `before_save` action, in this case when you call `Spec.where(message_id: self.id).order('id asc')` these specs are not yet saved to db

Comment: Oh I see.... any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: things you are trying to do in `before_save` can be achieved in the message controller action itself. You can easily create the specs along with the message upon receiving the form inputs. As you have defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for :specs` in `Message`, the `params` will contain specs related fields inside `specs_attributes`. Saving the message will also save the related specs. For details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: You're trying to query the database for the records before you saved them ... :'-)

Comment: @WasifHossain That is true, but the problem I'm having is not with saving specs, they do get saved, but I need to use them to save another field 'output' and that one does not get saved.

Comment: @Drenmi You're right... any suggestions how to do access the attributes before they are saved so I can achieve my goal?

Comment: as you didn't provide enough details on how your controller action is saving the Message as well as its `has_many :specs`, why don't you do it in `after_save` callback instead of `before_save`, as the message will eventually have its id assigned by the time `after` callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your like:

```
specs_array = Spec.where(message_id: self.id).order('id asc')
```

To:

```
specs_array = specs.order(:id)
```

Write a comment whether that helped?

Comment: `self` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work:/ same as before, nothing happens and output is saved as 'hola'

Comment: @NavidFalla Can you please include your controller method in your question? The one that calls save for message/specs